# How to get fcitx-mozc to work in linux?

Tags: japanese

I use fcitx-mozc for typing Japanese and I would like to use it in emacs over the inbuilt as it is more powerful.

I tried using mozc-mode (mozc.el) but that says there's "`communication error with the helper process".` I tried using fcitx.el and

```
(fcitx-aggressive-setup)
(setq fcitx-use-dbus t)
```

to my .emacs file and ran `fcitx-aggressive-setup` but neither work.

Comment: what's your operating system? how did you install mozc and mosc.el?

Comment: 4.17.4-1-MANJARO
M-x list-packages (i.e. elpa/melpa)

Comment: Also, fcitx-mozc from arch repo (i.e. pacman)

Comment: mozc.el states that it needs the `mozc_emacs_helper` binary. This file cannot be found in the arch repo package `fcitx-mozc`'s list of files. It looks like it is needed and it wasn't installed by pacman or mozc.el's {,m}elpa installation and that you'll have to find a way to install it yourself. Also, do mind that whatever binary you install it has to match {,m}elpa's version, so you might want to use `straight.el` for package management instead.